# Sum Total QTY of Widgets

Tags: excel-formula

I would like Cell E11 to be a "Smart Cell" that can SUM the total QTY of only items that match a catalog of items

In this example I'd like a formula that will SUM the QTYs of only a certain list of items. .

Example - what would be a formula for cell E11 that would only SUM the cells from the QTY column if the ITEM matches with either an HDU5, and/or HDU2, and/or, A35, and/or 298?  In this case that would equal 11 - I don't know how to make that actually happen

I would like the "catalog" of ITEMS that I want their QTYS summed to be part of the formula itself for easier maintenance purposes.

Thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT a SUMIFS():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(A:A,D:D,{"HDU5","HDU2","A35","298"}))
```